# Framing as unusual, 3rd degree polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this fubction: $f(x)= 2+3x^2-x^3$ on the interval $[1,4]$, by framing it, I got $ -59 \leq f(x) \leq 49$. Is it true?

Comment: It's not wrong, in that $f(x)$ is indeed between the numbers for $x \in [1, 4]$, but I got much tighter bounds. What do you mean by "framing" in this context?

Comment: I mean putting f(x) in a frame of values. Yeah, you get minimum of -14, much tighter

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by *"putting $f(x)$ in a frame of values"*. To me that suggests precisely the method described in Macavity's answer, which gives the tight bounds $-14\leq f(x)\leq6$. So that makes me wonder what you did.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is technically correct, though tighter bounds exist.  For these, without calculus apparatus, note...

$f(x)-2 = x^2(3-x) $, indicating there is a turning point at $x=0$, with value $f(0)=2$, and
$f(x)-6 = -(x-2)^2(1+x)$, indicating another turning point at $x=2$, and $f(2)=6$.

As this is a cubic, there are only two turning points, both of which are found above, so the only possible extrema for the cubic in $[1, 4]$ are when $x=1, 2, 4$, corresponding to $f(1)=4, f(2)=6, f(4)=-14$, thus $-14\leqslant f(x) \leqslant 6$ for $x\in [1, 4]$.